# Remove slash from htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404, slash

sorry for my bad english but i am using a translator ..
I should remove (and redirect) all url with slashes to url without slash

https://www.backupc.it/assistenza-da-remoto/

https://www.backupc.it/assistenza-da-remoto

https://www.backupc.it/aa/

https://www.backupc.it/aa

the problem is that leaving the slashes redirects me to the 404 page but without css also for the existing pages (the existing ones if there is the slash it gives me 404 error)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are `assistenza-da-remoto` and `aa` physical directories? The missing CSS is most certainly due to using relative URL-paths to your CSS files... see the following question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Answer (score 1):

I solved by trial and error (randomly)

I added the second part you see but I did not understand the meaning .. The fact is that it fell into place

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]


DirectorySlash Off
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Since you've removed the last `RewriteRule` directive, the last part is no longer valid. `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives work together to form a single rule. The `ErrorDocument` should not be in the `<IfModule>` wrapper. In fact, you should remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper (you have some directives inside and some outside anyway.)

Comment: Done, now the code looks cleaner.
Then, from what you see, you can tell me why the seo scanners tell me that I create duplicate pages for backupc.it and backupc.it/

Comment: The SEO scanners are wrong. `example.com` and `example.com/` are essentially the _same_ URL. Strictly speaking it is `example.com/` (with a slash). However, you will likely confuse the scanners if you are inconsistently linking to both. See this question on the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35643/is-trailing-slash-automagically-added-on-click-of-home-page-url-in-browser